# Failing to pass {history} object as a prop into Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am getting the following error when trying to pass the history object into my Router as a prop.  I just added the history={history} line to my Router and for some reason it is thinking it's not an object being passed in?

***index.js:1446 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `history` of type `function` supplied to `Router`, expected `object`.***

**history.js**

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import PostCreate from './posts/PostCreate';
import PostList from './posts/PostList';
import Header from './Header';
import history from '../history';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="ui container">

            <Router history={history} >
                <div>
                    <Header />
                    <Route path="/" exact component={PostList} />
                    <Route path="/posts/new" exact component={PostCreate} />
                </div>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I didn't have () at the end of my createBrowserHistory in my history.js.

**history.js**

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```